# How can i get json indexes as keys?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, indexing

The user of the api sends a json like this:

```
{ "0": "3♥", "1": "5♣", "2": "4♣",“3”: “9♥”, … }
```

im trying to save the the value of each index (3♥,5♣,4♣,9♥) in a list.

all I have now is the POST method but I dont know how to read it) OR i don't know if i need to use another type of request

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/start", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes= "application/json" )
public String getData(@RequestBody ?? ) { }
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Alejandra, welcome to Stackoverflow. So that you can get an answer I suggest you edit your question to clarify what exactly you are asking. How it is currently written I'm not able to help. Maybe add some code as without it its quite open ended!

Comment: @Ale unfortunately, the edit doesn't help. Try to explain what you want to achieve as clear as possible

Comment: You want `{ "0": "3♥", "1": "5♣", "2": "4♣",“3”: “9♥”, … }` as response when the `/start` POST request is triggered? Are you developing an API endpoint?

Comment: no its the other way! the json its the user input, and the output its the list, yes its an API im using springboot and java (sorry for the miss of clarity, its the language barrier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/start", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes= "application/json" )
    public String getData(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> data) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String val: data.values()){
        result.add(val);
        }
     }
```

We are storing the user input into a `HashMap` and then extracting its values in the `for` loop. You can ofcourse collect the data returned by `data.values()` into an `ArrayList` or any collection of your choice to avoid the `for` loop.

You can use `EntrySet` if you need both `key` and `value` like below

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  @PostMapping("/saveData")
  public ResponseEntity<String> saveData(@RequestBody Map<Integer, Object> data) {
    List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
    data.forEach(values::add);

    //Additonal code here, e.g. save

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
```

`@RequestBody Map<Integer, Object>` ensures that indexes will always be Integers. Value type can be changed to String.
If indexes are not int, 400 Bad Request will be returned. Indexes must be positive integers.

You can also user longer notation for adding elements to the list (might be more clear):
`data.forEach((key, value) -> values.add(key, value));`

```
For this payload:
{
    "0": "3♥",
    "1": "5♣",
    "2": "4♣",
    "3": "9♥"
}
```

That's the outcome:

[image]

Comment: THANKS! i didnt thought about the integers! thats nice I'll be trying